# How to get the oldest person in this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm practicing my javascript and I've come across the following array.

```
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Carly',
    yearOfBirth: 2018,
  },
  {
    name: 'Ray',
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941
  },
]
```

i'm trying to find the oldest person in the array but I keep getting the wrong person.here's my code

```
  let findTheOldest = function(people) {
    const oldest = people.sort((a,b) => (a.yearOfDeath - a.yearOfBirth) > (b.yearOfDeath - b.yearOfBirth) ? -1 : 1);
    return oldest[0];
   }
```

so it keeps saying that 'Carly' is the oldest person rather than 'Ray'? How would I go about it? note that 'Carly' has no yearOfDeath and therefore she is still alive.

Comment: When there's no year of death recorded you probably need to substitute the current year into that field before doing your calculation

Comment: when finding the oldest when there is no year of death you should use the current year in the calculation

Comment: Since they are still alive

Comment: Have a look at the solution I presented.

Comment: I would be tempted to question the logic of the task... I mean, do dead people even have an age? Then again, Google often tells us it's a dead persons 100th+ birthday, so maybe even death cannot stop you ageing? Meh, just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use sort to find the oldest, you need to include a default specifying the current year for people without a yearOfDeath. Below I've done this in a helper function called "age".

Using sort if your only purpose is to find a maximum can be inefficient though, particularly if you're dealing with a lot of data: try using reduce, as per other answer.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 2018,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
];

let findTheOldest = function (people) {
  const age = (x) => (x.yearOfDeath || new Date().getFullYear()) - x.yearOfBirth;
  const oldest = people.sort((a, b) =>
    age(a) > age(b) ? -1 : 1
  );
  return oldest[0];
};

console.log(findTheOldest(people));
```

Comment: Yes, but you only need to maximise the value. Sorting all the others is inefficient.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and use the current year for people without a death date:

```js
const people = [{name:"Carly",yearOfBirth:2018},{name:"Ray",yearOfBirth:1962,yearOfDeath:2011},{name:"Jane",yearOfBirth:1912,yearOfDeath:1941}];

const findTheOldest = function(people) {
  const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();

  return people.reduce((res, person) => {
    const age = (person.yearOfDeath || thisYear) - person.yearOfBirth;
    return age > res.age ? { person, age } : res;
  }, { person: null, age: 0 }).person;
}

console.log(findTheOldest(people)); // Ray
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this can work on a dataset of like 10m people. I tried and it didn't work

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed It works fine with 10m, and takes 0.2 seconds on my laptop, versus 9 seconds for your solution... (45x faster) [Yours](https://jsfiddle.net/qLd6bjuo/) / [Mine](https://jsfiddle.net/vqhmwxk8/)

Comment: Your bottleneck is that you calculate the current year twice per iteration. Storing it in a variable gives similar performance to mine  https://jsfiddle.net/fy5cxLgp/

Comment: Is it considered normal, in JavaScript circles, to write `for` loops with `reduce`?

Comment: @user253751 It's as normal as writing it with a `for` loop (you can do anything with a `for` loop). And if someone isn't familiar with `reduce`, they could certainly use a `for` if that makes them feel more comfortable with understanding the code. But a `for` loop adds complexity, and forces mutability _(you have to mutate a variable on every iteration to keep track of  a result)_. But JS provides `reduce`, which was made just for this purpose: Iterate over an array, and get a single result out of it. It's functional programming, immutability. If that tool was made for it, why not use it?

Comment: @user253751 I just remembered another user's description which totally sums up what I just said about using the right tool for the right task, if that makes more sense to you: [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz). `for` loops are generic. But specific tools are provided for specific types of tasks, so it makes more sense to me to use them. Especially when they allow immutability in the shape of functional programming

Comment: @blex This solution, however, adds extra complexity for the purpose of avoiding the use of features that are less complex. Mutability doesn't destroy the universe. In fact, *you've already written your code in a mutable style,* but then you've put all the local variables inside this `res` object which is technically immutable because you create a new one on each iteration. You've written mutable code and then, pointlesly, run it through a mutable-to-immutable translator.

Comment: Using `reduce` to simulate mutability is sensible in Haskell, where you *have* to do that, but Javascript isn't Haskell...

Comment: @user253751 I agree that it doesn't destroy the universe, and in a lot of cases like this particular one, does not matter :) Again, I've got nothing against `for` loops. I guess it's also a matter of personal taste. I can assure you that I didn't try _translating_ anything into _immutable code style_. That's just how I like to write code. I like keeping things enclosed, with pure functions, without side effects. To me, `reduce` comes more naturally than initializing a variable, looping, returning, when it comes to building a single result from an array. e.g https://jsfiddle.net/nz18te06/

Comment: @blex I mean your solution is naturally mutable (in any language other than Haskell): it contains variables which are updated on each iteration.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, internally. I meant from a dev's point of view

Comment: @blex from my point of view, your solution is *naturally* mutable.

Comment: @user253751 I'm sorry, I don't get it  But thank you for your feedback. I respect it

Comment: But if you can explain, or have a link to some resource, I'd be glad to know what you mean. Maybe (most certainly) we don't have the same definition of mutability. When I think about mutability, I think about a line of code explicitely overwriting or altering an existing variable. That's the reason why I tend to prefer using `const` over `let`, for example. That's what I have in mind, when I hear about immutability

Comment: @blex Right. You've written a solution that would be most naturally expressed using mutability. The immutable version has less efficiency and then relies on the compiler to turn it into the mutable version at runtime, to recover that efficiency.

Comment: @blex See Ahmed's accepted answer for the mutable version.

Comment: @blex yes, I edited my answer and credited the idea, Idk how I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As an Engineer, most proofs I study at college assume something and we work it out, then at the end of the proof, Maths will tell you if your assumption was right.

We'll assume we have a function called `getAge(person)` that has a signature as follows.

```
// this performance improvement of storing the year was suggested by @blex
let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
let getAge = (person) => {
    return (person.yearOfDeath ? person.yearOfDeath : currentYear) - person.yearOfBirth
};
```

Basically, if the person doesn't have a `.yearOfDeath`, he's still alive and the current year **2020** *at the time of writing this answer*.

and we have a `getOldest(people)` that has a signature as follows.

```
let getOldest = people => {
    /** Keep in mind that people can be mutated and you 
        need to avoid this here
    */

    // An assumption. It can be right or wrong.
    let oldest_person = people[0];

    // The first method (slice) returns a shallow copy
    // the second one (splice) removes the oldest_person
    // removing it makes the loop count decrease by one. Nothing else.
    // we don't need a deep copy, we won't alter the people.
    people = (people.slice()).splice(1);

    // You could save the getAge(oldest_person) in a variable
    // instead of computing it each time
    // I wanted this to be as readable as possible.
    for (let person of people){
        if (getAge(person) > getAge(oldest_person)){
            // Congrats! we have a new older person!
            oldest_person = person;
        }
    }

    return oldest_person;

};
```

This has a worst-case time complexity of o(n).

For illustration, let's benchmark this.

```
let people = []
let init = () => {

    let randomInteger = (min, max) => { 
      // return random integer between min, max, found this on stackoverflow
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){ // 10m person
        let dateOfBirth = parseInt('19' + randomInteger(10,99));
        let dateOfDeath = parseInt('20' + randomInteger(10, 99));

        let person = {
            name: `person_${i}`,
            dateOfBirth, // same as dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth,
            dateOfDeath, // same logic
        }

        people.push(person); // add it to people

    }
}

init();

start = performance.now(); // time in millisecs
getOldest(people);
end = performance.now();  // time in millisecs after getting the oldest person

console.log((end - start ) * Math.pow(10, -3)) // time elapsed is around 0.2 secs.
```

Comment: Thanks, this was well written! Studying engineering too!

Comment: 6 seconds seems a bit high. Is it faster the 2nd or 3rd time? (because of the JIT compiler)

Comment: @SamuelOkoth glad I could help

Comment: @user253751 Yea high, I copied the array and it took a lot of time to be copied

Comment: @user253751 The edit made it to 0.2s and I credited the one who alerted me